# Ubuntu 10.10 - Memory Issue with MySQL

Tags: mysql, memory, ubuntu

All of a sudden my Database Server is running around 98% Memory Allocation (I have a 16GB box running only a MySQL Instance).

Here is what is displayed when I do a free -m:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15498      14565        932          0         76       8081
-/+ buffers/cache:       6408       9089
Swap:        31743          0      31743
```

I've already rebooted the machine - It's running on a very high availability server. MySQL claims that it's running 562 queries per second.

```
Total   ø per hour  ø per minute    ø per second
22 M    2.03 M          33.77 k     562.90
```

Is this normal?

Comment: Swap:        31743          0      31743
looks ok to me.

Comment: how much swap memory is acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that memory stats. You still have about 9 GB free and no swap is used.